# Can Codable APIs be used to decode data encoded with NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData?

Tags: swift, nskeyedarchiver, codable, property-list

I'm converting a codebase from using `NSCoding` to using `Codable`. I have run into an issue when trying to restore data encoded with `NSCoding`. I have an object that was encoded with the code:

```
let encodedUser = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: user)
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(encodedUser, forKey: userKey)
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

It was previously being decoded with the code:

```
if let encodedUser = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: userKey) {
  if let user = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedUser) as? User {
    \\ do stuff
  }
}
```

After updating the `User` object to be `Codable`, I attempted to update the archive/unarchive code to use `PropertyListDecoder` because I saw that `archivedData(withRootObject:)` returns data formatted as `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0`. When running this code:

```
if let encodedUser = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: userKey) {
  let user = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(User.self, from: encodedUser)
  \\ do stuff
}
```

I get a `keyNotFound` error for the first key I'm looking for, and breakpointing in my `init(from: Decoder)`, I can see that the container has no keys. I also tried to use `PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:options:format)` to see if I could pass that result into `PropertyListDecoder`, but that function gave me an `NSCFDictionary`, which is structured in a really strange way but does appear to contain all the data I'm looking for.

So is it possible to decode an object using `Codable` APIs if it was encoded with `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:)`? How can I achieve this?

Comment: yes, you can! detail https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/migrating-to-codable-from-nscoding-ddc2585f28a4

Comment: @kunwang If you thoroughly read both my question and that article you will see that the article does not describe what I'm asking about at all. The solution in that article is to implement BOTH NSCoding and Codable, which is what I was very specifically trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that the answer is almost certainly no, you cannot use `Codable` to decode what `NSCoding` encoded. I wanted to get rid of all the `NSCoding` cruft in my codebase, and settled on a migration path where I have both protocols implemented in the critical data models to convert stored data from `NSCoding` to `Codable` formats, and I will remove NSCoding in the future when enough of my users have updated.